# i do not understand the usage of the first not true statement in the first line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I didn't understand the purpose of first not true statement
as i understand that
 if proceeds with statement if it is deemed true but in the following scenario shouldn't code return out no results ?

PS: I am just learning python for the first time and 
 would appreciate your valuable time and help

```
if not True:
   print("1")
elif not (1 + 1 == 3):
   print("2")
else:
   print("3")
```

The output of the following code turns out to be 2 I dont understand how?

Comment: The first clause is indeed useless: `print("1")` will never be executed, and the first two lines can be left out.

Comment: `not` just gives the boolean opposite of whatever follows it.  `True` is obviously `True`, so `not True` is always `False`.  `if False:` means the next block will never be executed.

Comment: The second clause is a weird way of rephrasing `if 2 != 3`, which is always true (in standard mathematics anyway), and thus `print("2")` is always executed (and the `else` clause is never executed either).

Comment: `1 + 1` will never equal `3` either, so this code could be written more simply as just `print("2")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first condition makes no sense. The default value of an expressionless boolean check is True, thus making the condition False.
2. It gets to the else-if condition which checks if (1+1 == 3) is False, which is True. thus printing 2.
3. An else statement is executed only if all the preceding if and elif conditions are not met.

Hence, the output turns out to be 2.

Comment: if True:
   print("1")

Comment: run this , here also there is no expression but still you will get 1 as answer

Comment: Yes, the default value of an expressionless boolean check is True in Python.

Comment: @ahmadjanan acc to your answer the default value of expressionless Boolean is true and for the first statement to be executed i.e. for printing of one the condition to be satisfied is that the expression should return false?

Comment: Yes. The first condition is checking whether the default value is "not True" which means False. Since, the default value is True and "not False", it is not satisfied and thus skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The first line will always be bypassed and will never get executed, the fact is if statement will check if the expression is true or false and doesn't really care about it if it seems logical or not, `if not True:` is not logical cause it's never going to get executed! but in some cases you need `while True` to create an endless loop, but for if statements it doesn't sound logical however it works.

Answer (score -1):

if tries to search for True condition here

so first condition ---> if not True (means) if False: print(1) -------> this is false condition and will never be executed in any case

2nd condition -------> else if not (1+1 = 3) ---> this is True condition. as 1+1 is not equal to 3

3rd condition ----> if above 2 conditions is not true , than print 3 but condition 2 is true hence answer will be (2) which is true

Comment: "if tries to search for True condition by default" this sentence is really weird, as it implies that `if` statements can be configured to do other things, which they cannot